# only execute a statement every millionth time in a loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a while loop that runs around 10 million times incrementing a variable "day" every time. I want the program to only print a line when a million days has passed (i.e.

1 million days have passed

2 million days have passed

...

Loop is done

so far I have the code:

```
double dayMill; //outside the loop
...
dayMill = day/1000000; //every runthrough of the loop
```

I was thinking about using an if statement with with things like

```
if( (int)dayMill == dayMill){}
```

because when day = 1,000,000 then daymill = 1 so cast as an int it is 1 as well. However this doesn't work. It prints 0.0 million days... a lot until 1.0 a lot..... never just the one line for each million i want

Comment: That's about once every 2739 years ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(dayMill % 1000000 == 0)
{
    //print statement
}
```

That is if you make dayMill an int. Why is it a double if you are incrementing by one? I guess I do not really understand what you are doing exactly.

Comment: actually just adding a .0 after dayMill = day / 1000000 works :) but this works too

Comment: @Killerpixler The modulo operator makes more sense in my opinion as this is its primary purpose, whereas dividing leaves the intent a bit more obscure.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
if (day % 1000000 == 0) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever your loop index is,

```
if (index % 1000000 == 0)
{
    // do your magic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulus

```
for (long i = 1; ; i++) {
    if (i % 1000000 == 0)
        System.out.println(i);

}
```

prints

```
1000000
2000000
3000000
4000000
5000000
6000000
7000000
... etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Or....

```
i++;
if(i == 1000000) {
    print stuff;
    i=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is:

```
int count = 0;
int times = 1_000_000;
while (true) {
    ....
    if ( ++count % times == 0 ) {
       ...
    }
}
```